# Failed to download file format on click of download button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Files of another format like .jpg are able to download but xlsx format
 is not able to download each time it just give error message failed to
download for xslx type format.Provide any solution for that error.

here is my code

```
public void run() {
    // Do stuff
    int dl_progress = 0;
    try {
        DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
        q.setFilterById(downloadIds[serial]);
        Cursor c = mgr.query(q);
        c.moveToFirst();
        long bytes_downloaded = c
                .getInt(c

.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
        long bytes_total = c
                .getInt(c

.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
        if (bytes_total == -1)
            dl_progress = 0;
        else
            dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100) / 
bytes_total);
        prefs.edit().putInt(name_of_da + "progress", dl_progress)
                .commit();
        switch (c.getInt(c
                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))) {
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                prefs.edit().putBoolean(name_of_da + "downloading", 
            false)
                        .commit();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                prefs.edit().putBoolean(name_of_da + "downloading", 
      false)
                        .commit();
                sendBroadcast(new Intent("refresh_downloads"));
                this.cancel();
                sendNotification(1, serial, name_of_da, dl_progress);
                this.cancel();
                countOfCurrent--;
                if (countOfCurrent == 0)
                    stopSelf();
                // }
                break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                // msg = "Download paused!";
                if (c.getInt(c

    .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)) ==
     DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK) {
                    if (errorFlag) {
                        errorFlag = false;
                        sendNotification(15, serial, name_of_da,
                                dl_progress);
                    }
                } else {
                    sendNotification(1, serial, name_of_da, 
        dl_progress);
                    this.cancel();
                    countOfCurrent--;
                    if (countOfCurrent == 0)
                        stopSelf();
                }
                break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                // msg = "Download pending!";
                sendNotification(0, serial, name_of_da, dl_progress);
                break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                // msg = "Download in progress!";
                errorFlag = true;
                if (startFlag) {
                    if (verifyFromSD(name_of_da)) {
                        startFlag = false;
                        sendBroadcast(new 
              Intent("refresh_downloads"));
                    }
                }
                if (dl_progress != prevProgr) {
                    sendNotification(0, serial, name_of_da, 
dl_progress);
                    prevProgr = dl_progress;
                }
                break;

            case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                // msg = "Download complete!";
                prefs.edit().putInt(name_of_da, 100).commit();
                prefs.edit().putBoolean(name_of_da + "downloading", 
     false)
                        .commit();
                prefs.edit().putBoolean(name_of_da + "downloaded", 
         true)
                        .commit();
                prefs.edit()
                        .putString(
                                name_of_da + "filepath",

                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        .toString()
                                        + "/Download/"
                                        + name_of_da).commit();
                sendNotification(0, serial, name_of_da, dl_progress); //                       
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Download complete: " //             
   + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + 
      "/Download/" + name_of_da //                                , 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                this.cancel();
                countOfCurrent--;
                if (countOfCurrent == 0)
                    stopSelf();
                break;

            default:
                // msg = "Download is nowhere in sight";
                sendNotification(10, serial, name_of_da, dl_progress);
                this.cancel();
                countOfCurrent--;
                if (countOfCurrent == 0)
                    stopSelf();
                break;
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        sendNotification(7, serial, name_of_da, dl_progress);
        cancel();
        countOfCurrent--;
        if (countOfCurrent == 0)
            stopSelf();
    }
}
}

public void sendNotification(int tmout, int nin, String name, int 
 progress) {
if (tmout == 0) {
    if (progress >= 100) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(
                getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet) ? 
      R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification
                        : R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Completed").setContentText(name)
                .setOngoing(false).setProgress(100, 100, false);
        Uri ttt = Uri.parse("file://"
                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "/Download/" + name);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String arr[] = name.split("\\.");
        MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String mimeType = myMime
                .getMimeTypeFromExtension(arr[arr.length - 1]);
        intent.setDataAndType(ttt, mimeType);
        prefs.edit().putInt("retry", 1).commit();
        PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),
                0, intent, 0);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(i);
        notificationManager.notify(nin, mBuilder.build());
    } else {
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Downloading: " + name)
                .setContentText(progress + " %")
                .setSmallIcon(
                        getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet) ?
 R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification
                                : R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification)
                .setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true);
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, false);
        notificationManager.notify(nin, mBuilder.build());
    }
} else {
    if (tmout == 1) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(
                getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet) ? 
         R.drawable.ic_abc_notification
                        : R.drawable.ic_abc_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Failed: " + name)
                .setContentText(progress + " %").setAutoCancel(true)
                .setProgress(100, progress, false).setOngoing(false);
        // Intent intnt = new Intent(Mp3Constants.NOTIFICATION);
        // intnt.putExtra("resume", "1");
        // intnt.putExtra("url", urlD);
        // intnt.putExtra("name", name);
        // intnt.putExtra("nin", nin);
        // PendingIntent i = PendingIntent
        // .getBroadcast(conte, 0, intnt, 0);
        // mBuilder.setContentIntent(i);
    } else if (tmout == 7) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(
                getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet) ? 
 R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification
                        : R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Cancelled: " + name)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setProgress(100, progress, false)
                .setOngoing(false);
        // Intent intnt = new Intent(Mp3Constants.NOTIFICATION);
        // intnt.putExtra("resume", "1");
        // intnt.putExtra("url", urlD);
        // intnt.putExtra("name", name);
        // intnt.putExtra("nin", nin);
        // PendingIntent i = PendingIntent
        // .getBroadcast(conte, 0, intnt, 0);
        // mBuilder.setContentIntent(i);
    } else if (tmout == 15) {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(
                getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet) ? 
 R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification
                        : R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Paused: " + name)
                .setContentText("Waiting for network...")
                .setAutoCancel(true).setProgress(100, progress, false)
                .setOngoing(false);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(
                getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet) ? 
      R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification
                        : R.drawable.ic_ibt_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Interrupted: " + name)
                .setContentText("No storage 
 found").setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(false);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(nin, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

This is error Log

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has 
  not called Looper.prepare()
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
 W/System.err:     at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:345)
 W/System.err:     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:100)
 W/System.err:     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:256)
 W/System.err:     at com.services.FileDownloadService$RegrowCornAnimate.run
 (FileDownloadService.java:252)
 W/System.err:     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

This is the Toast where that error jump on error log click

> Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed!"

Comment: This is due to the mime type issue

Comment: is this the only crash log ur getting or could u please post the entire crash log

Comment: You need to call Toast.makeText(...) from the UI thread:

Comment: This is only error log that is displayed in my logcat

Comment: Try removing the toast too

Comment: Try this 
   `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {` 
         `public void run() {` 
            `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` 
      `}` 
     `});`